# Apply multiple-output function to vector in R

Tags: r

I have a function that returns multiple outputs as a list. I want to apply this function to a vector of inputs, and collect the result into a list of vectors. The code below does what I want, but has a couple of drawbacks. First, I need to explicitly give the names "square" and "cube" of the output list of f. Second, I need to evaluate the function f twice for each value of x. Is there a way to get the same output as the code below while avoiding the drawbacks?

```
f <- function(x) list(square = x^2, cube = x^3)
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
desired.output <- list(
  square = sapply(X = x, FUN = function(x) f(x)$square),
  cube = sapply(X = x, FUN = function(x) f(x)$cube)
)
```

Comment: Can you do ` f(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be simply applying the function over x

```
f(x)
#$square
#[1] 1 4 9

#$cube
#[1]  1  8 27
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the semantic of functions that return lists, but this works!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the function `do.call` for this

```
do.call(f, list(x))
```

Comment: This answer also works, but I'm accepting the other answer because it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
> mapply(f, x)

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
square 1    4    9   
cube   1    8    27
```

OR

```
> Map(f,x)

[[1]]
[[1]]$square
[1] 1

[[1]]$cube
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$square
[1] 4

[[2]]$cube
[1] 8


[[3]]
[[3]]$square
[1] 9

[[3]]$cube
[1] 27
```