# Apply arbitrary function that returns a list to vector in R

Tags: r

I recently asked a similar question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983305/apply-multiple-output-function-to-vector-in-r/58983434#58983434)), but the example that I gave there was a little too simple, and the answers did not work for my actual use case. Again, I am using R and want to apply a function to a vector. The function returns a list, and I want the results to be formatted as a list of vectors, where the names of the output list correspond to the names in the list returned by the function, and the value for each list element is the vector of values over the elements of the input vector. The following example shows a basic set up, together with two ways of calculating the desired output (`sum.of.differences` and `sum.of.differences.2`). The first method (`sum.of.differences`) seems to be the easiest way to understand what the desired output; the second method (`sum.of.differences.2`) avoids two major problems with the first method -- computing the function twice for each element of the input vector, and being forced to give the names of the list elements explicitly. However, the second method also seems relatively complicated for such a fundamental task. Is there a more idiomatic way to get the desired results in R?

```
x <- rnorm(n = 10)
a <- seq(from = -1, to = +1, by = 0.01)

sum.of.differences.fun <- function(a) {
  d <- x - a
  list(
    sum.of.absolute.differences = sum(abs(d)),
    sum.of.squared.differences = sum(d^2)
  )
}

sum.of.differences <- list(
  sum.of.absolute.differences = sapply(
    X = a,
    FUN = function(a) sum.of.differences.fun(a)$sum.of.absolute.differences
  ),
  sum.of.squared.differences = sapply(
    X = a,
    FUN = function(a) sum.of.differences.fun(a)$sum.of.squared.differences
  )
)

sum.of.differences.2 <- (function(lst) {
  processed.lst <- lapply(
    X = names(lst[[1]]),
    FUN = function(name) {
      sapply(
        X = lst,
        FUN = function(x) x[[name]]
      )
    }
  )
  names(processed.lst) <- names(lst[[1]])
  return(processed.lst)
})(lapply(X = a, FUN = sum.of.differences.fun))
```

Answer (score 1):

What language did you learn before R? It seems as though you might be using design patterns from a different functional language (I'd guess Lisp). The following code is much simpler and the output is identical (aside from names) as far as I can tell.

```r
x <- rnorm(n = 10)
a <- seq(from = -1, to = +1, by = 0.01)

funs <- c(
  sumabsdiff = function(a) sum(abs(x - a)),
  sumsquarediff = function(a) sum((x - a) ^ 2)
)
sumdiff <- lapply(
  funs,
  function(fun) sapply(a, fun)
)
```

Comment: You are correct -- I have limited experience with R, and am undoubtedly using style from other languages I have used more extensively (like Lisp). Do you have any recommendations for where to learn good R style? Your version is much cleaner, but won't quite work for me. (My example may have been deceptively simply.) The issue is that my function is much more complicated and expensive than the one I gave in the question. It is relatively efficient to compute the list returned by the function in order to avoid repeating work. Adapting your answer would mean sacrificing this efficiency gain.

Comment: I think http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ is an excellent source for style and programming techniques. I'm not really following where this is less efficient; in fact using the example you posted my example is almost twice as fast: sum.of.differences takes ~680 us, sum.of.differences.2 takes ~500, my version takes ~320

Comment: The issue in your example is that in both cases you are performing a lot of redundant computation. Those approaches are almost obligately less efficient than mine. Maybe you can provide an example that's closer to the real thing?

Comment: @Stirling I'd strongly recommend the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) - it's a great introduction to base R concepts and efficiency.

Comment: I updated my second approach to be more realistic, by computing the difference vector d <- x - a once, and using this difference vector to compute both the sum of absolute differences and the sum of squared differences. This sharing work in computing the elements of the output list is the core of my question. It seems like your approach does not allow this sharing, and I am confused about why you say that my (second) approach has redundant computation that your solution avoids. On my computer with x having length 10^7, I'm finding that my modified second approach is a little faster than yours.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what your second example was doing when I looked earlier, I think you're right about computation. I think it's borderline incomprehensible though. Try `l <- lapply(a, sum.of.differences.fun); df <- do.call(rbind, l)`